# Iphone not receiving push notifications with APNS in command it is showing success

Tags: ios, node.js, apple-push-notifications

I have integrated push notifications using APNS in node. Response coming success but Iphone not receiving push notification.

Here is the code in node:

```
var iosOptions = {
    key  : 'pkey.pem',
     cert : 'cert.pem',
     debug    : true,
     port: 2195,
     enhanced: true,
     gateway  : 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',
     errorCallback : function(num, err) {
         console.error(err);
     }
 };

function sendNotification(request){
  sendIos(request.query.device_id, request.query.message, request.query.room, request.query.identity);
}

function sendIos(device_id, message, room, identity) {
   console.log(device_id, room, message, identity);
     let connection = new apns.Connection(iosOptions);
     let notification = new apns.Notification();
     notification.badge = 3;
       notification.sound = "default",
     notification.device = new apns.Device(device_id);
     notification.alert = "Hello World!";
     notification.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600;
     notification.payload = {"description" : "A good news !"};
     connection.sendNotification(notification);
 }
```

Getting response like this in console:
[Wed Mar 28 2018 18:07:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] Send : d0f36f59db02fecf3d3465c97335ad9067a2aca4992e429b7b9e1d97ac812017
[Wed Mar 28 2018 18:07:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] open socket

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Did you add the certificates for both debug and release ? Are you sure you're not using the wrong certificate ?

Comment: Yes, those are valid  certificates. I am getting success response here with those certificates. https://www.pushwatch.com/apns/

Comment: Check the payload. If you missed something you don't get any error, but not even the notification. The problem with certificates is not their validity, but if you use the debug certificate with the release version of your app or the opposite, you won't get any notification or error. This is a payload with an alert and a badge number: {
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received !" },
    "addInfo" : [ "Item1",  "Item2" ]
}

Comment: This is a simple payload with some additional data. An alert the badge number and some additional custom items: {
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "Alert",
      "body": "Message received !"
    },
    "badge": 1
  },
  "addInfo": [ "Item1", "Item2" ]
}. I'm using APNS myself and it works fine.